# How do I pass a current form field value to new popup?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a sales entry form where the user selects a boolean, "Has a trade?". When the form is submitted, my code displays a popup form tied to a separate datasource. The "Parent Stock No" field on this popup needs to come from the "Stock No" field on the initial sales entry form. I'm not having any success passing it forward.

I tried to modify my Submit/OnClick script to set the (source)Stock No field as a variable and then set the popup's field after making it visible, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
//Submit button, 'On Click' code.
app.closeDialog('AddSaleWindow');
var tradechk = widget.datasource.item.HasTrade;
if(tradechk === true){
app.popups.AddTradePopup.visible = true;
}
widget.datasource.createItem();
```

edit w/ working code - Used on a "Submit and add another" button. It passes a stock number and deal type to the second form.

```
var parentStkNo = app.popups.AddTradePopup.children.ParentStkNo.value;
var parentDealType = 
app.popups.AddTradePopup.children.TradeDealType.value;
widget.datasource.createItem();
app.popups.AddTradePopup.visible = false;
app.closeDialog('AddSaleWindow');
app.popups.AddTrade2Popup.visible = true;

app.popups.AddTrade2Popup.children.ParentStkNo.value = parentStkNo;
app.popups.AddTrade2Popup.TradeDealType.value = parentDealType;
```

Comment: The piece of code you included in your question does not appear to have your modified code where you are trying to pass your Stock No as a variable. Could you please include the modified code even if it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I solved my problem! Edited the OP with new code that works - let me know if there was a more efficient way to go about it.

Comment: Hi, when I try to do the above, I get `Type mismatch: Cannot set type String for property value. Type MY_DATASOURCE record is expected`. Any idea how to make it work.